# Replace SSLContext default with own implementation and trust manger

Tags: java, ssl, java-8

Based on this answer from Jcs ([HttpUnit WebConversation SSL Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868654/httpunit-webconversation-ssl-issues)) I tried to replace the `SSLContext.getDefault()` with my own trust manager.

```
SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getDefault();
ssl.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new AnyTrustManager()}, null);
ssl.setDefault(ssl);
```

AnyTrustManager():

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class AnyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager
{
  X509Certificate[] client = null;
  X509Certificate[] server = null;

  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
  {
    client = chain;
  }

  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
  {
    server = chain;
  }

  public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
  {
    return new X509Certificate[0];
  }
}
```

I need to do this because a 3rd party .jar is only using the SSLContext default which causes me some issues so for the duration of this action I have to change the default to something else and change it back later.

This will unfortunately throw a  `java.security.KeyManagementException: Default SSLContext is initialized automatically` exception.

How can I get this to work on Java 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "default" SSLContext is immutable. Therefore it is not possible the TrustManager instance. Instead you should replace

```
SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getDefault();
```

by (for instance)

```
SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
```