# Unable to invoke https REST endpoint through spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, https

I have to build a REST endpoint which is internally calling some REST Endpoints (Business Confidential) and will do some customization and give a user-specific response. Endpoints (Business Confidential) that I'm using inside the spring boot framework and support HTTP and https. Since my framework supports HTTP protocol by default.

**Sample Endpoint below:**

http://localhost:8081/hadoop-cal-endpoint-controller/getCustomDetails/customerID

The above endpoint which I created and internally it will call another REST Service (which support HTTP and https) and applied some custom logic and return some specific format output as Response.

I added below lines into application.yml file:

```
   ssl:
      key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
      keyStoreType: pkcs12
      keyAlias: tomcat
      key-store-password: password
   port: 8081
```

Used the below blog to create keystore.p12 file (copied the keystore.p12 file in src/main/resources foder):

https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

I started the spring boot application using spring-boot:run command and it ran successfully. I can able to open swagger API with https protocol as look like below:

[image]

Now the problem is whenever I tried to call the endpoints using HTTP or https inside the above client that is giving the below error message

```
 "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException",
  "message": "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
```

Everything works fine when I removed SSL and keep it as HTTP. But I just want to enable https and that endpoint will call another endpoint (Business confidential) and return a response.

Anyone, please help me on this?

**Updated:**

**stack traces:**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.online.paypal.hadoop.cal.swagger.utils.Utils.sendGET(Utils.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.online.paypal.hadoop.cal.swagger.controller.HadoopCALEndpointController.getETLResponseLive(HadoopCALEndpointController.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:606) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:524) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:461) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

Below is the code that will call the HTTP/HTTPS endpoint.

```
  public static String send(String URL) throws IOException {
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            //URL obj = new URL(null,url,new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            //HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            //con.setHostnameVerifier(new SSLVerifier());
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
            responseValue = responseCode;
            System.out.println(responseValue);
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

            } else {
                System.out.println("GET request not worked");
            }
            return response.toString();

        }
```

Certification Path:

[image]

Updated the code as mentioned in the StackOverflow question that mentioned by Deadpool

[HttpsUrlConnection using KeyStore instead of TrustStore with WebSphere Liberty Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578653/httpsurlconnection-using-keystore-instead-of-truststore-with-websphere-liberty-p)

```
FileInputStream truststoreFile = new FileInputStream(".//src//main//resources//keystore.p12");
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            char[] trustorePassword = "password".toCharArray();
            truststore.load(truststoreFile, trustorePassword);
            trustManagerFactory.init(truststore);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            KeyManager[] keyManagers = {};//if you have key managers;
            sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

**Observed Error:**

```
"status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException",
  "message": "handshake alert:  unrecognized_name"
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your internal HTTP call uses the keystore you assume to use? Please append the code that calls the endpoints out of your application.

Comment: Also some stack trace from the spring boot application could be helpful

Comment: may be this one might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find

Comment: So, where in your code do you use the KeyStore?

Comment: https enabled but when I tried to call another End point inside @REST controller which is returning the above error message.

Comment: @smutje  I'm not sure how can I handle keystore in code. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpsUrlConnection using KeyStore instead of TrustStore with WebSphere Liberty Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578653/httpsurlconnection-using-keystore-instead-of-truststore-with-websphere-liberty-p)

Comment: I wonder this error message is from controller end point or by code that calling another endpoint in service ? @ArrchanaMohan

Comment: In your SSL certificate, set "Subject Alternatif Name" >  Dns Name=localhost.

Comment: The code is calling another endpoint in service and observed that error message. I just mentioned the sendGET(String url) which is calling the other end point.

Comment: check your certification path

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_introduction.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your service provider uses a self signed certificate. You either have to add the selfsigned certificate to `cacerts` known certificates to whitelist it or run your application with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` parameter

Here is details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146838/6785908

Quoting relevant parts here

> The problem appears when your server has self signed certificate. To
> workaround it you can add this certificate to the list of trusted
> certificates of your JVM.
>
> [In this article](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html) author describes how to fetch the certificate
> from your browser and add it to cacerts file of your JVM. You can
> either edit `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file or run you
> application with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` parameter. Verify which
> JDK/JRE you are using too as this is often a source of confusion.
>
> See also:
> [How are SSL certificate server names resolved/Can I add alternative names using keytool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using)
> If you run into `java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found` exception.

Or if it's just for testing purpose, why not just tell your process to skip the cert validation

like this: https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html

Or

Modern way of invoking a rest service using Spring's WebClient (and
ignoring the cert) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441205/6785908

Comment: I just downloaded the .cer file and imported as mentioned in that link and ran the service and still its failing. Can you please tell me what I should mentioned in the application.yml file after imported .cer file in cacert.

Comment: Can you please help me on this. I'm completely blocked and googled but didn't find any right resources. It would be great if you give me some sample code that fix my issue.

Comment: Hi @ArrchanaMohan, I am more than happy to help. Could you just checkin both Rest producer and consumer code to a github repo where the issue is reproducible

Comment: Did you check your cacerts file for the new entry

Comment: Yes I did. I exported the.cer file from the https through browser and imported into cacert file, and reboot the service and tried but still no luck

Comment: Is it possible to use cert.pem and key.pem file to use and fix the certification issue? I just got those file from certification team. How can I use those to resolve this issue. Yours idea and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: since It deal with some live records and I cant push the code to Git hub.   That's the really paining part.

Comment: https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html This will unblock you from doing the local testing. But it's a security concern, dont do this in production

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan.. here is the code that suppresses the hostname and cert validation checks, https://github.com/jaisonpjohn/spring-scratchpad/tree/master/spring-boot-https-

Comment: clone it and run application.java (server), then run the client. If you remove the static block , it will reproduce your issue

Comment: https://github.com/jaisonpjohn/spring-scratchpad/tree/master/spring-boot-https-pkcs12 -- updated the URL

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan.. Did this work for you. If it did, please accept the answer.

Comment: Nope still no luck. I tried to hit https like in that code but It returned {
  "timestamp": "2020-01-10T13:16:26+0530",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException",
  "message": "I/O error on GET request for \"https://hadoop.qa.amazon.com/idsearch/environment/amzon/id/47b46cfb08f8c47b46cf\": handshake alert:  unrecognized_name; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name",

Comment: Try switching to Spring's WebClient than the apache web client. Refer my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/to/keystore.jks

Comment: Is it system.setProperties? can you please tell me where I need to use this in the above code?